# How can I verify that my TLS server is encrypting traffic?

Tags: ssl, go, encryption, https, tls1.2

I've set up a TLS server in Go using a custom generated certificate/key pair. Is there an easy way for me to test that the content of my HTTP requests to this server is indeed encrypted when it gets sent out over the network? For my own sanity I'd like to compare and contrast the content of the packets when I use TLS vs normal HTTP.

Comment: Sniff it with Wireshark.

Comment: Fwiw, no browser will do HTTPS without encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sniffer, here are two: [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com), it has a 30 day free trial period and is easy to use. Or [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org), it is free and you will hate using it.

Comment: Why would one hate using Wireshark? It's very easy to use and quite powerful.

Comment: Wireshark is quite powerful and that is part of the problem if you only need to see HTTP/HTTPS traffic and are a new or occasional user. If one needs to see HTTPS traffic Charles easily installs a certificate, and one can see traffic that has not been pinned. I have spent extensive time using both. For low level work Wireshark is the way to go.

Comment: I've been using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) with some success. Stable for Windows only but they've got beta builds for Mac & Linux.